# Crew rank in gta 5 online

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

How come when I got online today my crew rank was at 17, the other day I was 127, why did my crew rank drop?

Comment: in-game or social club rank?

Comment: Isn't 17 BETTER than 127 in terms of rank?

Comment: No. Online crew rank in game goes from 1 up I was high now I can't even put crew color smoke on my tires.

Comment: Have you changed crews. You can have up to 6. If you are removed from the crew and re-added my the moderator you lose your rank. Not if you switch. Check your crews.

Comment: No never. I have different ones but no. I have been in this crew for the past 3 months I believe. But I was just playing the other day at a high crew rank. (Just talked to a crew member told me I was rank 150 in the crew) but today upon playing I seen I was level 17

Comment: I just logged on again and in and im at level 14 in the crew now.

Comment: Now I'm level 1! -.-

Comment: Check the Social club site. socialclub.rockstargames.com

Answer (score 1):

Contact rockstar support to restore your progress. https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us  Sign in with your rockstar id and post a question on the site. This happened to me to- I was rank 21 and got reseted to 1 and lost all me progress If you contact them they should get back to you in less then a day, time and restore your progress, as they did for me.[image: I got a mail back in less than 5 hrs.]